# How To Implement Custom Tree Columns and Cells In Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to implement custom columns in Eclipse RCP for tree component. Columns like Combo or a selection button that can display another selection dialog. By default, Eclipse tree columns only support raw text strings. I want to replace the simple TextBox (or label) with another control. How can I achieve that? 
The following example implements a simple text cells.

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER);
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
}
table.getColumn(0).setText ("Task");
table.getColumn(1).setText ("Progress");
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item.setText("Task " + i);
}
table.getColumn(0).pack();
table.getColumn(1).setWidth(128);
shell.pack();
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
    }
}
display.dispose();
```

Comment: That is really an SWT app not an Eclipse RCP or plug-in. For Eclipse you would use JFace TableViewer with OwnerDrawLabelProvider, for SWT you use the SWT.MeasureItem/PaintItem/EraseItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put Controls there, it's probably not because you can only display text (which itself isn't exactly true), it's because you want the contents to be editable. So use cell editors[1](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/CellEditor.html). You can written tutorials at https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html
and http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/TableCellEditorComboTextandButton.htm .

Comment: That might require the TreeEditor from the same package. Your example code uses Table classes, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to use Nebula project for this reason. (https://eclipse.org/nebula/)